how to resolve pixel jittering in javacv generated video
I am trying to generate video using images, where image have some overlays text and png icons. I am using javacv library for this.
Final output video seems pixelated, i don't understand what is it since i do not have video processing domain knowledge, i am beginner to this.
I know that video bitrate and choice of video encoder are important factor which contributes to video quality and there are many more factors too.
I am providing you two output for comparison, one of them is generated using javacv and another one is from moviepy library
Please watch it in full screen since the problem i am talking about only gets highlighted in full screen, you will see the pixel dancing in javacv generated video, but python output seems stable
https://imgur.com/a/aowNnKg - javacv generated
https://imgur.com/a/eiLXrbk - Moviepy generated
I am using same encoder in both of the implementation
Encoder - libx264
bitrate - 
   800 Kbps for javacv 
   500 Kbps for moviepy

frame rate - 24fps for both of them

output video size -> 
    7MB (javacv)
    5MB (Moviepy)



generated output size from javacv is bigger then moviepy generated video.
here is my java configuration for FFmpegFrameRecorder
        FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(this.outputPath, 
                                           this.screensizeX, this.screensizeY);
        if(this.videoCodecName!=null && "libx264".equals(this.videoCodecName)) {
            recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
        }
        recorder.setFormat("mp4"); 
        recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420);
        recorder.setVideoBitrate(800000);
        recorder.setImageWidth(this.screensizeX);
        recorder.setFrameRate(24);


and here is python configuration for writing video file
Full_final_clip.write_videofile(
                            f"{video_folder_path}/{FILE_ID}_INTERMEDIATE.mp4",
                            codec="libx264",
                            audio_codec="aac",
                            temp_audiofile=f"{FILE_ID}_INTER_temp-audio.m4a",
                            remove_temp=True,
                            fps=24,
                        )


as you can see i am not specifying bitrate in python, but i checked that bitrate of final output is around 500 kbps, which is lower then what i specified in java, yet java generated video quality seems poor.
I have tried setting crf value also , but it seems it does not have any impact when used.
increasing bitrate improve quality somewhat but at the cost of file size, still generated output seems pixelated.
Can someone please highlight what might be the issue, and how python is generating better quality video, when both of the libraries use ffmpeg at the backend.
Edit 1 : also, I am adding code which is being used to make zoom animation for continuous frames, As somewhere i read that this might be the cause for pixel jitter, please see and let me know if there is any improvement we can do to remove pixel jittering
private Mat applyZoomEffect(Mat frame, int currentFrame, long effectFrames, int width, int height, String mode, String position, double speed) {
        long totalFrames = effectFrames;
        double i = currentFrame;
        if ("out".equals(mode)) {
            i = totalFrames - i;
        }
        double zoom = 1 + (i * ((0.1 * speed) / totalFrames));

        double originalCenterX = width/2.0;
        double originalCenterY = height/2.0;
   

        // Resize image
        //opencv_imgproc.resize(frame, resizedMat, new Size(newWidth, newHeight));

        // Determine crop region based on position
        double x = 0, y = 0;
        switch (position.toLowerCase()) {
            case "center":
                // Adjusting for center zoom
                 x = originalCenterX - originalCenterX * zoom;
                 y = originalCenterY - originalCenterY * zoom;
                 
                 x= (width-(width*zoom))/2.0;
                 y= (height-(height*zoom))/2.0;
                break;
        }

        double[][] rowData = {{zoom, 0, x},{0,zoom,y}};

        double[] flatData = flattenArray(rowData);

        // Create a DoublePointer from the flattened array
        DoublePointer doublePointer = new DoublePointer(flatData);

        // Create a Mat object with two rows and three columns
        Mat mat = new Mat(2, 3, org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_core.CV_64F); // CV_64F is for double type

        // Put the data into the Mat object
        mat.data().put(doublePointer);
        Mat transformedFrame = new Mat();
        opencv_imgproc.warpAffine(frame, transformedFrame, mat, new Size(frame.cols(), frame.rows()),opencv_imgproc.INTER_LANCZOS4,0,new Scalar(0,0,0,0));
        return transformedFrame;
    }


I don't see you setting the frame rate to 24 in the Java code.

@TimRoberts Hi Tim, thanks for pointing out, it is my bad, i missed it while copying the code, but i have set it, and even i tried multiple frame rates , it did not solve my issue

Is Python also doing the zoom effect?

@TimRoberts Yes , python also doing zoom effect with the same concept

I don't see it offhand.  I suggest you get a tool like VLC and look at the details of the video stream.  Maybe there are differences in the header fields that will pop out.

@TimRoberts VLC shows similar conf, same codec and frame rate, bit rate is different but as i already mentioned that i generated the video with similar bitrate but it did not help , so i had to increase bitrate for java version to  minimize that pixel jitter atleast, Only H264 encoder version seems different which is Lavf58.29.100 for moviepy and for java its newer version Lavf60.16.100
